# AJAX issue involving & symbol with string. 

Tags: html, ajax, forms, post

I have a hidden input that takes the article name. With a title that has the symbol "&" in it.

```
<input name="art" type="hidden" id="art" value="<?php echo $rew['art']; ?>"/>
```

When I submit my form, the $_POST doesn't register the full article title. It only goes up to the point where the & was, and the rest is blank.

I want this: "This is & was."

But I get: "This is ".

How can I make it so that when I submit a form I get the "&" symbol and the remaining context.

I'm also searching in the database as well. My problem right now is getting the remaining parts of the title after "&"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape HTML entities via the [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function:

```
<input name="art" type="hidden" id="art" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($rew['art']); ?>"/>
```

---

Based on discussion in the comments below, you also need to escape the ampersand in the URL you're generating for an Ajax request. You can do this in JavaScript with the [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm) function:

```
var dataString = '&topic' + encodeURIComponent(topic);
```

Comment: Remember to specify your character encoding. Here's some reading on that subject: http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2012/03/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-cross-site-scripting-xss-in-php-part-1-how-not-to-use-htmlspecialchars-for-output-escaping/

Comment: I tried that. It wouldn't work. Because even when it's in &amp; format, it still goes through my form as &. The form just doesn't want register that symbol. Is it possible because it's a ajax form?

Comment: That's very odd. Can you post the output of `print_r($_POST)` when you've submitted this form using `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: Yeah. It only shows the the characters before the "&". But as I look at my code, I'm starting to think its my jquery+ajax. Because in the code, the var datastring is setup like this: 
var dataString = '&topic='+ topic;

Is it possible that the amp symbol in the script is casuing this error? Where after the & it's trying to find another string?

Comment: Yes, that's almost certainly the problem. You should update your original question to explain that you're also using Ajax. I've updated my answer with another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `&` with `&amp;`